# jquery attr.() only working in firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

I have a  tag with different options, if you choose an option it is supposed to change the font-family of an inputfield. This works great in firefox but not responding in either IE or Chrome. This is how my option looks like

```
<option onclick="$('#blogEntrySubject').attr('style', 'font-family:Arial;');">My option</option>
```

Is this wrong?

Comment: Potentially a typing mistake in the question, but you have an additional (and possibly problematic) single quote at the end of your onclick attribute.

Comment: May or may not be relevant, but you have a superfluous single-quote at the end of your tag: `);'">`. Should it not be `);">`?

Comment: Your right, but just a typo from my side. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

`<option>` Does not have an onclick event by default in other browsers than Firefox. So what you have to do is adding an onchange event to the `<select>` tag. So for me to change the font I set my option like this:

```
<option value="Arial">Arial</a>
```

And my select looks something like this:

```
<select onchange="$('#blogEntrySubject').css('font-family', this.value);">
```

This works in all broswers. Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose one could say that is wrong, yes. Use the [`css(propertyName, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to manipulate the applied styles directly:

```
$('#blogEntrySubject').css("font-family", "arial");
```

Also, as noted in comments by now: beware stray quotes.

Comment: This works in firefox as well but not in chrome or other browsers. Can't figure out any possible reason why this happened?

Comment: I realised that it works in chrome if i use links instead of an select>option. Why is this do you know?

Answer (score 2):

should be

`$('#blogEntrySubject').css('fontFamily', 'Arial');`

Comment: fontFamily does not work it seems. I realised that it works in chrome if i use links instead of an select>option. Why is this do you know?